# Sumar/multiplicar de fila a fila en distintas tablas

Tags: php, mysql

vengo con esta duda que tengo ¿Cómo puedo sumar en de fila en fila en distintas tablas?

```
Tabla 1
Id_Servicio Id_Gasto Cantidad
1             1         15
2             1         20
3             1         88 
1             2         14
2             2         12
3             2         10


Tabla 2
Id_Gasto  Nombre  Costo
1          Hojas    .5
2          Folder    1

Tabla 3
id_Servicio  Nombre
1            Libros
2            Revistas
3            Etc...
```

Acá está mi ejemplo de lo que intenté x.x pero me suma todo y luego lo multiplica por todo y ya luego me da el resultado.

```
Select SUM (tab2.costo * tab1.cantidad) as Total
From tabla2 as tab2, tabla1 as tab1, tabla3 as tab3
where tab1.ID_Gasto = tab2.ID_Gasto AND tab2.ID_Servicio = tab3.ID_Servicio
```

Básicamente lo que quiero es sumar la multiplicación de la cantidad 1 de la tabla 1 por el precio del gasto 1, y eso sumarlo a la multiplicación de la cantidad 2 con el gasto 2. Y eso dependiendo el servicio. [Por eso es que se repite el id del servicio en la primera tabla]

Gracias de antemano por ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Planteemos tus 3 tablas en un ejemplo, para poder hacer algunas pruebas:

```
-- TABLES

CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  servicio_id int,
  gasto_id int,
  cantidad int,
  CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  gasto_id int,
  nombre varchar(255),
  costo DECIMAL(6, 4) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk2 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE t3 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  servicio_id int,
  nombre varchar(255),
  CONSTRAINT pk3 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- INSERT

INSERT INTO t3 (servicio_id, nombre) VALUES 
(1, 'libros'),
(2, 'Revistas'),
(3, 'Etc...');

INSERT INTO t1 (servicio_id, gasto_id, cantidad) VALUES 
(1, 1, 15),
(2, 1, 20),
(3, 1, 88),
(1, 2, 14),
(2, 2, 12),
(3, 2, 10);

INSERT INTO t2 (gasto_id, nombre, costo) VALUES 
(1, 'Hojas', 5),
(2, 'Folder', 1);
```

Ahora realicemos algunas consultas de prueba, primero unamos las 3 tablas por sus claves foraneas con unos join:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.gasto_id = t2.gasto_id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.servicio_id = t3.servicio_id;
```

Esto nos arroja un resultado similar al siguiente:

```
| id | servicio_id | gasto_id | cantidad | id | gasto_id | nombre | costo | id | servicio_id |   nombre |
|----|-------------|----------|----------|----|----------|--------|-------|----|-------------|----------|
|  1 |           1 |        1 |       15 |  1 |        1 |  Hojas |     5 |  1 |           1 |   libros |
|  2 |           2 |        1 |       20 |  1 |        1 |  Hojas |     5 |  2 |           2 | Revistas |
|  4 |           1 |        2 |       14 |  2 |        2 | Folder |     1 |  1 |           1 |   libros |
|  5 |           2 |        2 |       12 |  2 |        2 | Folder |     1 |  2 |           2 | Revistas |
|  3 |           3 |        1 |       88 |  1 |        1 |  Hojas |     5 |  3 |           3 |   Etc... |
|  6 |           3 |        2 |       10 |  2 |        2 | Folder |     1 |  3 |           3 |   Etc... |
```

Ya tenemos todas las columnas que necesitamos para hacer las operaciones en una sola tabla/consulta, bien, calculemos la cantidad todal de todos los registros, `SUM(cantidad * costo)`:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.cantidad * t2.costo) total
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.gasto_id = t2.gasto_id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.servicio_id = t3.servicio_id;
```

Resultado:

```
| total |
|-------|
|   651 |
```

Vayamos un paso mas allá y agrupemos los registros por el servicio_id para obtener un listado de la cantidad total de cada servicio:

```
SELECT t3.nombre, SUM(t1.cantidad * t2.costo) total
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.gasto_id = t2.gasto_id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.servicio_id = t3.servicio_id
GROUP BY t3.servicio_id;
```

Resultado:

```
|   nombre | total |
|----------|-------|
|   libros |    89 |
| Revistas |   112 |
|   Etc... |   450 |
```

O también por el gasto:

```
SELECT t2.nombre, SUM(t1.cantidad * t2.costo) total
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.gasto_id = t2.gasto_id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.servicio_id = t3.servicio_id
GROUP BY t2.gasto_id;
```

Resultado:

```
| nombre | total |
|--------|-------|
|  Hojas |   615 |
| Folder |    36 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar realizando un inner Join de tus tablas y aplicar la función SUM de tu multiplicación de los campos de tus tablas

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT TablaSumaServicio.id_Servicio,Tabla3.Nombre,SUM(TablaSumaServicio.Total) AS totalSuma FROM Tabla3
inner join (
   Select Tabla1.Id_Servicio, Tabla1.cantidad*Tabla2.Costo as Total From Tabla1
   INNER JOIN Tabla2 ON Tabla2.Id_Gasto=Tabla2.Id_Gasto
   order by Tabla1.Id_Servicio
) as TablaSumaServicio ON TablaSumaServicio.Id_Servicio=Tabla3.id_Servicio
```